# ¿Como verficar codigo OTP en angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, servicio, ng

Quiero hacer una verificacion de número, la verificacion del otp ya la hace la api, lo que yo quiero hacer ahora es desde el frontend mandarle en el body el numero de telefono y el codigo otp. Es algo sencillo pero recibo un error ¿alguien sabe como podria hacerlo?

Tengo el siguiente servicio para verificar el codigo otp:

Servicio.ts

```
checkOtpCode(cellPhone: string, otp: string){
    const body = {cellPhone, otp}
    return this.http.post(environment.api_URL + "otp/validate-invited-phone", body )
  }
```

En el ts del componente:

```
//get que obtiene el servicio que mantiene la info en el local storage
    get bookingModel(): BookingModel | undefined { return this.bookingService.bookingModel };

 otp!: string;
  verify: any;

   ngOnInit(): void {
    // Abro la data que tengo almacenada en el local storage
    this.verify = this.bookingService.loadData(); 
    //muestro el objeto almacenado en el local storage 
    console.log('object :>> ', this.bookingService.bookingModel);
  }

   onOtpChange(otp: string){
    this.otp = otp;
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log(this.otp);
    // credential me trae el numero almacenado en el local storage 
    let credential = this.bookingService.bookingModel.patient?.phone
    // trae el otp que escribio el usuario en pantalla
    let otp = this.otp;
    console.log('phone', credential, otp);

    this.bookingService.checkOtpCode(credential, otp).subscribe(res => {
      //si todo salio bien
      console.log(res);
      //enviame a la ruta relativa
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['../pagar'], { relativeTo: this._activedRoute });
      })
    })
  }
```

component.html

```html
<div class="otp">
        <ng-otp-input #ngOtpInput (onInputChange)="onOtpChange($event)" [config]="config"></ng-otp-input>
        <button class="btn btn-success mt-4" (click)="handleClick()">Verify OTP</button>
    </div>
```

Intente hacer la verificación del número, pero obtengo un error en credential del tipo: "Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)"

Porfavor, alguien si me ayuda, le estare muy agradecida

Comment: Pues en algún sitio tienes algo declarado como `string | undefined` y lo estás intentando guardar en una variable de tipo `string`, cuando debería ser también `string | undefined`, eso es lo que te dice el error. Sin ver el código de tus servicios y modelos es imposible saber exactamente qué pasa, pero deberías poder encontrarlo facilmente. Por cierto... no es necesario declarar las variables como tipo `loquesea | undefined` ya que undefined significa que no está definido... no hace falta definir algo como que no está definido, no estar definido ya es definición suficiente de `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Debes validar que ambas variables no sean `undefined`. Al usar el modo estricto en angular todas las variables deben ser declaradas. Tienes dos opciones, definir todo según su tipo o trabajar con el opcional a `undefined`. Lo siguiente debería quitar el error.

```javascript
    let credential = this.bookingService.bookingModel.patient?.phone
    // trae el otp que escribio el usuario en pantalla
    let otp = this.otp;
    if(crendential && otp)
        this.bookingService.checkOtpCode(credential, otp).subscribe(...)
```

Nota que estoy validando primero que las variables no sean `undefined`.

Comment: Hola! Primeramente gracias por responderme y explicarme, logre solucionar el error, pero fiajte que cuando quiero verificar el otp, enviando en el body el numero y el otp, no me deja. Es como si el otp y el credential los estuviera ignorando, no se si tengo que convertirlos en json o que debo hacer. Te dejo los archivos, tal vez podrias hecharle un vistazo si no es mucho abusar de tu amabilidad, tal vez tu vez de primera mi error, yo no lo logré, por mas que lo intenté e investigue: https://github.com/IzliaB/otp

Comment: Revise los archivos, pero es difícil saber que buscar sin más detalles. Te invito a realizar otra pregunta, o si esta relacionado con esto, actualiza tu pregunta con los nuevos datos.